# Question about mutation of multiple nuclei?

Tags: molecular-genetics

If an organism with multiple nuclei, such as the slime mold Physarum polycephalum, was to be exposed to a mutagen, such as 5-bromouracil, what would be the effect (besides death)? Especially if multiple nuclei were effected differently by the exposure.